# What theoretical distribution could this data be coming from?

Tags: regression, distributions

I am trying to build a regression model to predict a variable whose count histogram and QQ plot is given blow. Does anybody have any idea know what theoretical distribution could this variable be coming from? Any particular transformations that can be applied to this data that would make it more amenable to linear regression?

Count histogram:

[image]

QQ plot (for normal distribution with mean -1, std 8.5 (estimated from samples)):

[image]

Comment: Of greater importance for regression is information about how this variable may be related to the explanatory variables.  Its (univariate) distribution alone tells you almost nothing about whether or how to transform it.  Consider explaining what this variable means and supplying some information about those relationships.